# Django - How to make UNIQUE constraint not apply across inherited models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

There's a `PlainModel` that has attributes like `name`, `color` - and a `slug`, which has to be unique. I want to make my own version of it, an `ExtendedModel` that also has `size`. So, I made the model inherit from `PlainModel`:

```py
class ExtendedModel(PlainModel):
    size = models.IntegerField(...)
```

However, I ran into an issue - because of the way Django model inheritance works, `ExtendedModel`'s database table only has two columns - one for `size`, and one for a pointer to the original `PlainModel` table. This means that the unique constraint on `slug` applies for both models, and there can't be an `ExtendedModel` with the same `slug` as an already existing `PlainModel`. I don't want this behavior, the `slug`s are only going to ever appear in the context of each model separately (e.g. `/products/{slug}` and `/products/extended/{slug}`), so there's no reason to ensure uniqueness across them both. Is it possible to make the constraint apply only for each model respectively?

An obvious way would be to have the tables be completely separate, which Django does not seem to support, however. `PlainModel` would have to be an "Abstract Model", which I can't control. (`PlainModel` is defined in an external library.) Another way would be to relax the unique constraint and check in my own code - which doesn't seem to be a great solution, I would prefer if it was still ensured on a database level. Finally, I could just copy paste the relevant attributes from `PlainModel` to `ExtendedModel`, but then I lose the benefits of "inheritance" (i.e. ensuring that the models have some set of common attributes).

Comment: If `ExtendedModel` is an *abstract* model (`abstract = True` in the `Meta`), then the uniqness will only span over the child models.

Comment: So I'd create an abstract `AbstractExtendedModel` that inherits from `PlainModel`, and then an "actual" `ExtendedModel` that inherits from `AbstractExtendedModel`?